# Закрыть форму поиска по клику вне его?

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом. Если Нажимаем на иконку поиска. открывается окно ввода. Если я передумал что то вводить, нужно его закрыть кликом в любое место экрана, а не опять на иконку.

```
    $('.header-search-wrapper .search-main').click(function(){
    $('.search-form-main').toggleClass('active-search');
    $('.search-form-main .search-field').focus();
  
});





    <div class="header-search-wrapper">
  <span class="search-main">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </span>
  <div class="search-form-main clearfix">
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
 <label>
<input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" class="search-field" id="s" placeholder="Поиск" />
 <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" class="search-submit" >
</label>
</form>
<div class="result-search">
<div class="result-search-list"></div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно на всю страницу сначала открывать полупрозрачный элемент, а окно ввода сделать дочерним к нему. При клике на этот фоновый элемент как раз и отрабатывать функцию сворачивания как модального окна так и фона.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо повесить обработчик на все клики

```
$(window).on('click', function(evt) { // слушаем все клики
  if (!evt.target.closest('.header-search-wrapper .search-main')) { // если клик не внутри .header-search-wrapper .search-main
 if ($( '.search-form-main').hasClass( 'active-search' )) {
    $('.search-form-main').toggleClass('active-search');
}
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное!!!

Comment: Рада, что смогла помочь=)

Comment: Виктория, я заметил что у меня теперь поиск открывается кликнув на любую точку экрана... как исправить?

Comment: Я скопировала $('.search-form-main').toggleClass('active-search'); из вашего поста, а должен удаляться этот класс, если он есть, например, if ($( '.search-form-main')).hasClass( 'active-search' ) {  $('.search-form-main').toggleClass('active-search') } Сейчас поправлю ответ, чтобы не копировали с ошибкой

Comment: теперь вообще не открывает поиск((

Comment: if ($( '.search-form-main')).hasClass( 'active-search' )) {
-------------------
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: Исправила в главном ответе, там скобка была лишняя

Comment: Все работает. Спасибо огромное. Самая Лучшая!

Comment: Виктория, я только заметил что у меня окно поиска закрывается не только по клику в любое место, но и если кликнуть в поле куда печатать тест для поиска. Как исправить? Спасибо

Comment: У вас сейчас слушает АБСОЛЮТНО все клики, я просто не знаю структуру вашего сайта. Вы можете прописать область, нажатие по которой будет обабатываться как клик или указать области, которые исключить(просто допишите уловие `if (!evt.target.closest('.header-search-wrapper .search-main')) `)